# what is the proper way to convert between mysql datetime and python timestamp?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html.  i got to find a way to convert the string value  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' to a timestamp int.

i looked up in python's doc.

i tried:

```
print(time.strptime('2013-01-12 15:27:43', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

python give me a result like this.

time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=15, tm_min=27, tm_sec=43, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=12, tm_isdst=-1)

i tried this to convert timestamp to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format

```
print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.time()))
```

python give me a type error.

i only use timestamp to calculate time and date, i hope there's already a way in python, simple and efficient , and don't have to create temp data.

according to the answer i write two methods. hope it would be helpful

```
import time

def convertTimestampToSQLDateTime(value):
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(value))

def convertSQLDateTimeToTimestamp(value):
    return time.mktime(time.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: why don't you like to do it in mysql?

Comment: in the future i might not use mysql,so better solve the problem in python

Comment: related: [to convert datetime to posix timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279)

Comment: which is better to use when writing to database: using utc_timestamp in mysql or python datetime

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Happy to update this if I'm not properly understanding, but here are a few examples which may help. Note that this uses the `datetime` module instead of `time`.

```
>>> import datetime
```

Here we set up an example timestamp `ts` and a format `f`:

```
>>> ts = '2013-01-12 15:27:43'
>>> f = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Similar to what you did above, we use the `strptime` function (from `datetime.datetime`) to convert our string into a `datetime` object based on the formatting parameter:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, f)
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 12, 15, 27, 43)
```

Now in reverse - here we use `datetime.datetime.now()` to get the current time as a `datetime` object:

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 12, 0, 46, 54, 490219)
```

In the `datetime` case, the `strftime` method is actually called on the `datetime` object itself, with the formatting parameter as an argument:

```
>>> now.strftime(f)   
'2013-01-12 00:46:54'
```

In your situation, the reason you were getting an error is because `time.time()` returns a float:

```
>>> time.time()
1357980846.290231
```

But `time.strftime` needs a `time` tuple, similar to what you had above. Without getting into the maddening spiral that is time, a function such as `time.localtime()` will return the aforementioned `time` tuple and will return as you expect:

```
>>> now = time.localtime()
>>> now
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=0, tm_min=55, tm_sec=55, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=12, tm_isdst=0)
>>> f = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
>>> time.strftime(f, now)
'2013-01-12 00:55:55'
```

Comment: good indeed.im not looking for datetime solution but you also give the time solution .use time.localtime() to convert the timestamp data ,and its inverse function is time.mktime().

Comment: @Max Right on, let me know if any other questions come up :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm only adding this class to potentially save the next guy a little time. If anyone finds this useful, upvote RocketDonkey's answer.

```
## dev on v3.7.6

from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime, time


class Time:
    '''\
*Convenience class for easy format conversion*\n
Accepts time() float, datetime object, or SQL datetime str.\n
If no time arg is provided, object is initialized with time().\n
id kwarg can be used to keep track of objects.\n
Access formats as instance.t, instance.dt, or instance.sql.\
    '''

    f = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

    def __init__(self, *arg, id=None) -> None:
        self.id = id
        if len(arg) == 0:
            self.t = time()
            self.dt = self._dt
            self.sql = self._sql
        else:
            arg = arg[0]
            if isinstance(arg, float) or arg == None:
                if isinstance(arg, float):
                    self.t = arg
                else:
                    self.t = time()
                self.dt = self._dt
                self.sql = self._sql
            elif isinstance(arg, datetime):
                self.t = arg.timestamp()
                self.dt = arg
                self.sql = self._sql
            elif isinstance(arg, str):
                self.sql = arg
                if '.' not in arg:
                    self.dt = datetime.strptime(self.sql, Time.f)
                else:
                    normal, fract = arg.split('.')
                    py_t = datetime.strptime(normal, Time.f)
                    self.dt = py_t.replace(
                        microsecond=int(fract.ljust(6, '0')[:6]))
                self.t = self.dt.timestamp()

    @property
    def _dt(self) -> datetime:
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(self.t)

    @property
    def _sql(self) -> str:
        t = self.dt
        std = t.strftime(Time.f)
        fract = f'.{str(round(t.microsecond, -3))[:3]}'
        return std + fract

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        if self.id == None:
            return self.sql
        else:
            return f'Time obj "{self.id}": {self.sql}'


def test():
    def test_one(*arg):
        t = Time(*arg, id=type(*arg))
        print(t)
        print(t.t)
        print(t.dt)

    sql = '2020-01-22 15:30:33.433'
    time_float = 1579927395.3708763
    dt_obj = datetime.now()
    for datum in [sql, time_float, dt_obj, None]:
        test_one(datum)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```