# Convert MySQL datetime to wx.Python listCtrl Item

Tags: mysql, datetime, wxpython

My current developmental *wxPython* application uses various *listCtrl*'s to display the results of *MySQL* searches. From there an item can be selected so that further details can be displayed. The problem I am having is getting a *MySQL datetime* to display in the column. I have previously converted strings to a *MySQL* format but seem to have got bogged down doing the reverse!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291636/what-is-the-proper-way-to-convert-between-mysql-datetime-and-python-timestamp

Comment: I would suppose that unless you show us the "MySQL datetime" format that you are trying to convert, anyone answering would only be guessing.