# Python MySQLdb - how to convert the datetime.datetime?

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I get this kind of result from `MySQLdb` - `datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 13, 16, 52, 53)`

How can I convert it into something readable, such as '2011-11-03 18:21:26'?

```
   # Open database connection
   db = MySQLdb.connect(user = "root", passwd = "xxx", db = "python", host = "127.0.0.1", cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

   # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
   cursor = db.cursor()

   # execute SQL query using execute() method.
   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

   # Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
   data = cursor.fetchall()

   print data
```

result,

> ({'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'user_id': 4L,
>   'created_on': None, 'address': None, 'updated_on':
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 13, 16, 52, 53)}, {'first_name': 'Jane',
>   'last_name': 'Heart', 'user_id': 5L, 'created_on': None, 'address':
>   None, 'updated_on': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 13, 16, 52, 53)},
>   {'first_name': 'Dom', 'last_name': 'Robinsons', 'user_id': 6L,
>   'created_on': None, 'address': None, 'updated_on':
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 13, 16, 53, 33)}, {'first_name': 'Pete',
>   'last_name': 'Hand', 'user_id': 7L, 'created_on': None, 'address':
>   None, 'updated_on': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 13, 16, 53, 33)})

Comment: Have you tried datetime.fromtimestamp instead?

Comment: I believe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291636/what-is-the-proper-way-to-convert-between-mysql-datetime-and-python-timestamp) will point you to the right direction