# Running an SQL query based on a specific date and time

Tags: python, sql, datetime

I am a python newbie and I have an SQL query which I need to run in a python script which extracts data between yesterday's date at 08:00AM UTC and today's date at the same hour.
I do not know how to represent the exact date and times in Python.
Can someone help please?

Comment: What SQL implementation are you using (e.g. MySQL)? and are you using a db tool like SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291636/what-is-the-proper-way-to-convert-between-mysql-datetime-and-python-timestamp

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datetime.isoformat()`

try something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime  

yesterday = datetime(2016,2,15,8,0,0).isoformat(' ')
today = datetime(2016,2,16,8,0,0).isoformat(' ')
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MyTABLE WHERE INSTANT BETWEEN '" + yesterday + "' AND '" + today + "'")
```

More info in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat).

In order to calculate today and yesterday (at 08h00) autmatically you can do like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime(datetime.now().year, datetime.now().month, datetime.now().day, 8, 0, 0, 0)
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)

>>> today.isoformat(' ')
'2016-02-18 08:00:00'
>>> yesterday.isoformat(' ')
'2016-02-17 08:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I am using MySQL and what I am actually trying to do is to set yesterday's date at 08:00 as a variable and today's date at 08:00 into a second variable and then use them in the SQL query so that every time I run the script it will always calculate the data from yesterday's date at 08:00 to today's date at 08:00

Comment: `today = datetime(datetime.now().year, datetime.now().month, datetime.now().day, 8, 0, 0, 0)` and 
`yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)`
don't forget to import datetime and timedelta from `datetime`
I added this to my answer.